# Grunt task runs, but running each dependency task individually fails

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am trying to modify our grunt 'build' task but I am having trouble determining how it works.  We have a task defined as follows:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', [
  'clean:dist',
  'useminPrepare',
  'concurrent:dist',
  'autoprefixer',
  'concat',
  'copy:dist',
  'cdnify',
  'ngmin',
  'cssmin',
  'uglify',
  'filerev',
  'usemin:html',
  'usemin:css'
]);
```

This works fine, but if I try to run each task in this list individually, on the 'concat' task I get:

> No "concat" targets found.

Sure enough, the "concat" task is commented out:

```
// not used since Uglify task does concat,
// but still available if needed
/*concat: {
  dist: {}
},*/
```

I thought maybe it was just ignoring these tasks, but my final product is missing some of my ".js" files when I run each command individually this way.  What am I missing, here?

1. Why does concat work with no definition when I run `grunt build` but not when I run `grunt concat`?
2. Why would I get different results running `grunt build` than running `grunt clean:dist`, `grunt useminPrepare`, etc. in sequence?

Comment: what makes you say it "works" if the task is commented off? Does grunt not say anything when you run it? As for things not working when you run them in sequence, that depends entirely on how the actual tasks have been defined. Without code, no way to answer.

Comment: When i run `grunt build`, it prints out 'running concat:dist' after it finishes running autoprefixer.

Comment: Is it possible useminPrepare is automagically creating a 'concat' task?

Comment: https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin#the-useminprepare-task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [usemin updates the grunt config](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin#the-useminprepare-task) like you're thinking. If you run them at the same time the concat task is defined.

`grunt useminPrepare concat`